# JWT : The token could not be parsed from the request

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I am using jwt for CRUD in my controller, I have products and want to save the $user_id in database :

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $this->user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'price' => 'required|integer',
      'quantity' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $product->user_id = $this->user;
    $product->save;

    if ($product)
      return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'product' => $product
      ]);
    else
      return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Sorry, product could not be added'
      ], 500);
  }
```

It works fine but i used :

> $this->user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

In some of my methods in controller , so I want to prevent repeating that and write it in construct of my controller, but when I run:

> php artisan route:list

It shows this error:

> The token could not be parsed from the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of JWTAuth that you're using doesn't integrate itself nicely with Laravel and should probably be avoided for that reason.

That aside, the reason you're getting this is that your requests don't exist properly when the constructor is called. Instead, open up you base controller (typically `app/Http/Controllers/Controller`) and add the following method.

```
protected function user() {
    return JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
}
```

That way whenever you want the user, you can just do `$this->user()`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as above. I used `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source`. Could you tell me what version I should be calling that _does_ play nicely with Laravel?